# GDCM library cannot read dicom file in C#

Tags: c#, dicom, gdcm

I tried to read a DICOM file using GDCM library using this code :

```
gdcm.ImageReader imagereader = new gdcm.ImageReader();
imagereader.SetFileName(@"E:\sample_success.dcm");
if (!imagereader.Read()) throw new Exception("Cannot read dicom file!");
```

For "sample_success.dcm" file, I can read the file just fine ([sample_success.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAViW.png)).
But using "sample_failed.dcm" file, GDCM throws exception because it couldn't read it. I tried to open the file using other DICOM viewer such as Radiant and it worked. Is there something wrong with my GDCM build? Why it cannot read it?

I use GDCM 2.6.5. Please find both samples [here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wtl3fjye2yrvzno/samples.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're file contains garbage (bunch of binary 0) after offset `0x1480aa` (somewhere in the Pixel Data attribute). What did you expect from a toolkit if not report properly an error ?

By design GDCM will still load whatever it can until the error. So if you remove your `new Exception` in your code, you can decide (for example) to pass the `imagereader.GetFile()` to a `gdcm::Writer` and rewrite the file as clean DICOM.

As a side note I do not have access to `Radiant` software but I find it very odd that it does not indicate an error in that case.

I've checked with DCMTK and dicom3tools they all report a parsing issue.

Using the gdcm command line tool you can almost rewrite the file clean using:

```
$ gdcmconv -I sample_failed.dcm sample_failed_correct.dcm
```

Because your input dataset is invalid, GDCM (falsely) believe to see an attribute, you can remove it using:

```
$ gdcmanon --dumb --remove 0,0 sample_failed_correct.dcm sample_failed_correct_clean.dcm
```

And then:

```
$ gdcminfo sample_failed_correct.dcm 
MediaStorage is 1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.3.1 [Ultrasound Multi-frame Image Storage]
TransferSyntax is 1.2.840.10008.1.2.4.50 [JPEG Baseline (Process 1): Default Transfer Syntax for Lossy JPEG 8 Bit Image Compression]
NumberOfDimensions: 3
Dimensions: (800,600,21)
SamplesPerPixel    :3
BitsAllocated      :8
BitsStored         :8
HighBit            :7
PixelRepresentation:0
ScalarType found   :UINT8
PhotometricInterpretation: YBR_FULL_422
PlanarConfiguration: 0
TransferSyntax: 1.2.840.10008.1.2.4.50
Origin: (0,0,0)
Spacing: (0.0106324,0.0106324,1)
DirectionCosines: (1,0,0,0,1,0)
Rescale Intercept/Slope: (0,1)
Orientation Label: AXIAL
```

Which is valid with the number of Fragments in the Pixel Data:

```
$ gdcmdump sample_failed_correct.dcm | grep Item | grep "ff.d8" | wc
     21     126    2856
```

Comment: How to rewrite the file using code? I tried to pass `imagereader.GetFile()` to an ImageWriter and the result file is empty. Since 'imagereader.Read()' failed, it won't return any image.

Comment: @rg11 updated my answer. Simply pass the `gdcm::File` to a `gdcm::Writer`